# Descargar archivo xlsx con simplexlsxgen desde una llamada ajax

Tags: php, ajax, excel

Estoy intentando descargar un archivo xlsx generado en una página php usando una llamada ajax

```
await $.get({
          url: "./?action=export_excel",
          data: parametros,
          beforeSend: function(data) {
            $("#loader").html("<img src='res/images/ajax-loader.gif'>");
          },
          //console.log(data);
          success: function(data) {
           // ¿qué hacer aquí?
          }
    });
```

Estoy usando esta libreria https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen. Por el lado PHP tengo codificado lo siguiente:

```
xlsx = SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray( $data );
$xlsx->downloadAs('books.xlsx');
```

No se cómo hacerlo llegar al cliente.

Comment: Esa librería te crea un archivo Excel. ¿Qué quieres hacer luego con ese archivo?

Comment: quiero descargarlo desde el cliente usando la llamada ajax que puse

Comment: Tendrías que crear un Blob con la respuesta de Ajax, desde el `success` revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29556434/5587982), tiene precisamente un ejemplo para crear un Blob desde un archivo Excel. Lo que te interesa es a partir de esta parte: `var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});` porque la petición Ajax en la respuesta es distinta a la tuya, es una petición escrita en Javascript puro y la tuya está escrita en jQuery.

Comment: En tu caso, empezarías a crear el Blob así: **`var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});`**

Comment: tengo un require("core/controller/simplexlsx/SimpleXLSXGen.php"); y lo que llega al ajax es el contenido de la clase, no estoy usando composer para instalar. La página es PHP MVC sin framework.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que no estás seguro si tienes bien instalada la librería?

Comment: no se por qué envía el contenido de la clase como respuesta.

Comment: ya se como arreglarlo